# c# mvc3 razor - alternatives to foreach loop on matching List items in Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm a newbie at MVC / Razor and I need a bit of direction.  I'm trying to create training calendar that retrieves dates from a MongoDB database. The solution I have below works, but looking at it, I know that it can be done more efficiently, and would like some pointers.

Here is the code for a div on my page which is ONE day of the month... I have four months on a page. `Model.TrainingDays` is a `List<TrainingEvent> TEvent`. A `TrainingEvent` instance has the following properties:

```
string CssClass
string EventName
```

Here's my razor code (where `_day` is the day of the month we are rendering:

```
<div class="day">
    <div class="dayBox">@_dayNumber.ToString("00") <span class="black">@_day.ToString("ddd")</span></div>

    @foreach (var item in Model.TrainingDays)
    {
        if (_day.Date == item.Date.Date)
        {
            string eventCls = "eDay " + item.TEvent.CssClass;
            <div class="@eventCls">@item.TEvent.EventName</div>
            break;
        }
    }
</div>
```

If the date of the the `TrainingEvent` matches the current `_day` div we're in, add the Event.  The foreach loop is just not the best way to do this if I have a lot of events.
How ***should*** I be doing this?  This is also my first posting, so any advice on how I'm asking the question  is appreciated.
Many thanks!
Tim

Comment: Why is the foreach loop not the best way if you have lots of events?

Comment: Why it is that bad? it's working fine inside my app which loops over thousands of items with no overhead on the performance.

Comment: Is there only one event per Date? It would seem like it by looking at the "break" statement in your loop; if that is the case, then you should be using the "FirstOrDefault" Linq expression to filter down your result and your code would look more compact.

Comment: @taylonr Tim is looking only for a single match to print, notthe whole list.Note the break.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Indeed I did miss that.

Comment: yep, for clarification, this code is for only one event per day, but a more robust future solution would be to allow for more than one, but I still woulndt want to iterate over my whole list of events for each day. Thanks everyone for their help so far!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<div class="day">
    <div class="dayBox">@_dayNumber.ToString("00") <span class="black">@_day.ToString("ddd")</span></div>

    @foreach (var item in Model.TrainingDays.Where( td => td.Date.Date == _day.Date ))
    {
            string eventCls = "eDay " + item.TEvent.CssClass;
            <div class="@eventCls">@item.TEvent.EventName</div>
            break;
    }
</div>
```

Comment: +1 but worth mentioning you're not *eliminating* the loop with this, you're just hiding it behind a method call.

Comment: Mithrandir, does your example only iterate over matching Event Dates and not the whole list of dates? If so, I think this is a good solution

Comment: @TimMorrison : that's the idea. The where extension method filters only the matching dates and the outer foreach has to process only successful matches.

Comment: This gives me a `Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type` error. I have the `System.Data.Linq` refs...

Comment: @TimMorrison: it depends on what _day.Date is. Your code doesn't give enough detail. Maybe you will habe to evaluate it like "DateTime tmp = _day.Date" and then use "tmp" in the lambda.

Comment: `DateTime _day = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DayNumber);`

Comment: going to mark Mithrandir's answer, but still can't get the code to work...more googling required :(

Answer (score 1):

You could group the TrainingDays by the date, then convert them to a dictionary if you're really concerned about a performance hit. I'm not sure of the Razor syntax for it, but you would do this in normal C#:

```
var trainingDaysByDay = Model.TrainingDays
    .GroupBy(td => td.Date.Date)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key);
```

Then you could just look up the items for that day by doing:

```
foreach(var item in trainingDaysByDay[_day.Date])
{
    //...
}
```

This way you only iterate through the entire collection of TrainingDays once, and for each day you only touch the particular objects that you need. Unless you have a huge dataset, though, the difference is going to be negligible.

Comment: This also gives me a `Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type` error - am I missing something? I have added `system.data.linq` references to my project and the views folder

Comment: I'm not quite sure. As I said, I'm not too familiar with MVC. You could do the grouping in the controller, then put it in the ViewBag. Not the most elegant solution, but worth a try.